# Why splitting the word in this way is crashing?

Tags: c

I executed the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{char *a="awake";
 printf("%s\n", *(a+1));
 return 0; // expected out_put to be wake
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*(a+1)` is the same as `a[1]` which is a `char`, not the `char *` that `printf` expects for the `%s`.

**EDIT**: clarification: `printf` needs an address for the `%s` specifier, `a+1` is such an address (namely the address of the second character in the string), but `*(a+1)` then gives the *value* at that address. Which is just a character and in all likelyhood not a valid memory location for `printf` to read.

Comment: May be i'am completely wrong but as far as i know in this case a+1 gives the address of string but not the value stored in string. So i used *(a+1) to attain the characters starting from w i.e. wake (though not worked). i did not understand how it was printed though we gave only address alone.

Comment: `a+1` *is* the address of the second character in the string, but `*(a+1)` gives the value at that address. `printf` needs the address, not the value.

Answer (score 5):

You're dereferencing the pointer, which makes it a `char` but trying to output a string. Change your print statement to `printf("%s\n", a+1);`

Comment: May be i'am completely wrong but as far as i know in this case a+1 gives the address of string but not the value stored in string. So i used *(a+1) to attain the characters starting from w i.e. wake (though not worked). i did not understand how it was printed though we gave only address alone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to defrefeence the `char *`:

```
printf("%s\n", (a+1));
```

does what you want.

Comment: May be i'am completely wrong but as far as i know in this case a+1 gives the address of string but not the value stored in string. So i used *(a+1) to attain the characters starting from w i.e. wake (though not worked). i did not understand how it was printed though we gave only address alone.